# Can't get es-MX resource file to be used

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on a localized wp7 app and in the process of building my resx files and running into a issue where the es-MX file is not getting used when the phone is set correctly. I have a es-ES file also and the strings from it are being used instead of the es-MX file.

Here is the supported cultures from my csproj:

```
<SupportedCultures>en-GB;es-PE;es-MX;it;fr;nl;es-ES;</SupportedCultures>
```

And when check the CurrentCulture for the thread it is returning es-MX. But the strings are being loaded from the es-ES file.

Thanks for any help.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the examples at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx this was still not working correctly. This came down to not getting differences between es-ES and es-PE not be picked up correctly.

Added this line of code to App() in App.XAML.cs brought it all together.

```
AppResources.Culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the es-MX Culture is not supported on the Windows Phone OS 7.0 or 7.1, but the es-ES Culture is, and that's why is using that instead.

For a complete list of supported cultures see this blog [What languages and cultures are supported in WP7?](http://blog.themagicsoftware.com/2012/02/what-languages-and-cultures-are-supported-in-wp7.html) or this link [Culture and Language Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Regards,

Gerardo Melendrez

[The Magic Software](http://www.themagicsoftware.com)